# Injecting IAccessTokenProvider failing when using custom AuthenticationStateProvider - Blazor Wasm

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on a Wasm Blazor application, and I'm using OidcAuthentication via Identity sever.  For testing I use Mock authentication by implementing a custom AuthenticationStateProvider that simply adds few claims to the user context.  In some of my components I inject the TokenProvider to get my token and pass it to some javascript reporting library that needs a token. When I use normal security without the custom AuthenticationStateProvider, everything works but when I switch to the custom AuthenticationStateProvider I get errors when injecting the IAccessTokenProvider

```
public class MockAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public IOptionsMonitor<WasmMockClaimsPrincipalOptions> MockClaimsPrincipalOptions { get; }
    public MockAuthenticationStateProvider(IOptionsMonitor<WasmMockClaimsPrincipalOptions> options)
    {
        MockClaimsPrincipalOptions = options;
    }
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0
    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var mcp = MockClaimsPrincipalOptions.CurrentValue;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mcp.Selected))
        {
            var claims = mcp.Pool[mcp.Selected].ToClaimEnumerable();
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "mockAuth", "username", "role");
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
        }
        var anonymous = new ClaimsIdentity();
        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(anonymous)));
    }
}

services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, MockAuthenticationStateProvider>();
services.AddAuthorizationCore();

services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
{
     options.AddAuthorizationPolicies(config);
});

 services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
 {
            config.Bind($"{configKey}:Provider", options.ProviderOptions);
            config.Bind($"{configKey}:User", options.UserOptions);
  });
```

crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__0`3[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=5.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=5.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.OidcProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=5.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].<AddRemoteAuthentication>b__0_1(IServiceProvider sp) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__1(ServiceProviderEngineScope p) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateInitializer>g__Initialize|2(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent instance) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateComponent(Type componentType) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame& frame, Int32 parentComponentId) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()

Comment: Can you show code of the custom AuthenticationStateProvider?

Comment: I added code in  the original post.  Thank you

Comment: The exception is telling something about the `RemoteAuthenticationState`. Do you have that code as well?

Comment: RemoteAuthenticationState is the default implementation of IAccessTokenProvider. It's injected by .Net

Comment: @YassirYaghzar did you figure this out?